# Where to put final case classes?

Tags: scala

I know this is subjective. But I want to know what other people do and best practice. Do you put them in the same class where they are being used or create a new file and put all case classes in there or some other ways?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a part of a public interface (parameter or a value returned by a public function) put them in a separate class. It makes them easy to find even without using IDE features.

If it is a case class used only by private functions in *one* class, move it to the file containing that class.

If you need it in more than one place you can assume it is a public class, so it should be in a separate file.